# Pandas dataframe assign value to lists based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   id  cola colb
0   0   0    [1]
1   1   1    [2,3,4]
2   1   2    [2,3,4]
3   2   3    [3]
4   2   4    [3]
5   2   5    [4]
6   3   6    [5]
...
```

and want it to convert to:

```
   id  cola colb      colc
0   0   0    [1]       
1   1   1    [2,3,4]   0
2   1   2    [2,3,4]   0
3   2   3    [3]       1,2
4   2   4    [3]       1,2
5   2   5    [4]       1,2
6   3   6    [5]       1,2,3,4
...
```

The rule is:

Take first row for example, colb=[1], corresponding cola=0, then cola=0 is appended to cell list in colc for id=[1].

Take second row for example, colb=[2,3,4], corresponding cola=1, then cola=1 is appended to cell list in colc for id=[2,3,4].

Take third row for example, colb=[2,3,4], corresponding cola=2, then cola=2 is appended to cell list in colc for id=[2,3,4].
...

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
df['colc'] = [[] for _ in range(len(df))]
for i in range(len(df['colb'])):
    lista = df.colb[i]
    for j in lista:
        df.colc.loc[df.id==j].append(pd.Series(df.cola[i]))
```

But it seems that something is wrong at `df.colc.loc[df.id==j]`, no value has appended to the list. Is there anyway to do this? Could someone be so kind to help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [0,1,1,2,2,2,3],
    'cola': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'colb': [[1], [2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3], [3], [4], [5]],
})
```

`colb` is a column of list of `id`, `cola` is what we use to form `colc`, so we can pick out those columns, rename them, and explode the renamed column of `id` such that all lists are exploded into rows. Exploded rows will share the same `colc` value before.

```
step1 = df[['colb', 'cola']].rename(columns={'colb': 'id', 'cola': 'colc'}).explode('id')
```

Then we can `groupby` to form lists for different `id`

```
step2 = step1.groupby('id')['colc'].apply(list)
```

And finally merge those lists back

```
df.merge(step2, on='id', how='left')
```